# Combine Duplo feet with regular LEGO

Tags: building, design, duplo, connections

I would like to place this [Duplo pig](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=pig02pb01&name=Duplo%20Pig%20Adult%20Third%20Version%20with%20Lowered%20Head&category=%5BDuplo,%20Animal%5D#T=S&C=28&O=%7B%22color%22:28,%22iconly%22:0%7D) directly on Lego bricks/pieces. I tried an intermediate Duplo 2x4 plate with Lego bricks underneath, but it doesn't look good. The problem is that Duplo feet surround the studs. Therefore, Duplo feet don't fit onto Lego studs. Is there an elegant way to connect Duplo animals' feet with the Lego world?

[image]

@Uli found promising solutions, one of them is to use the [Technic Engine Piston Round](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=220#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D). It has some clutch power and at least transfers the issue into the regular LEGO world. Now I have to find a way to connect tow ball pieces to the rest of my MOC, Uli has provided some ideas.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Scientific progress goes OINK!**

[image]

This is an older DUPLO pig from the 70's, and its different design offers us some new possibilities.

For example there's a **rectangular hole** below the neck.

[image]

Now before we go any further, the LEGO policeman would like to remind everybody that stuffing plates into rectangular holes or jamming them between studs isn't exactly HIS cup of tea. Thank you very much.

[image]

That said, a one-by plate and tile will fit tightly into the hole under the neck. The tile allows for further details, more on that in a moment.

The one-by plate is then attached to a jumper plate. So this will be a snout, sorry, SNOT thing of a sort.

A wedged plate that sits between the hind legs will add some lateral stability.

[image]

Alright, so here's piggy (sporting a black Colin Furze style tie/ tile) now safely tied onto some crazy contraption.

And here's piggy sticking his (red tile) tongue out at our LEGO purists.

[image]

*THBPBPTHPT!*

---

[image]

EDIT: As it turns out, a **piston** has the right size. Conveniently, it can be attached to any *tow ball* piece.

[image]

EDIT: Added a close-up

[image]

Comment: It might not be a solution for pig in question, but it was fun to read.

Comment: I like the facial expression of my pig. This post makes me think. Maybe SNOT is the answer to my question.

Comment: @Aziraphale Following an edit by Uli I did test this with couple of Duplo pieces I have and can confirm that Technic Engine Piston works fine, not too tight, not too loose.

Comment: @Alex, you are right, see updated question. Uli, how did you find this solution??

Comment: @Aziraphale pure coincidence, tested out every stud shaped bit of LEGO I found in my bins.

Comment: @Aziraphale Added a close-up...

Answer (score 6):

I am still waiting for the bricklink delivery with 27448 tiles that Alex suggested in one comment of his answer. Therefore, I tried a less subtle solution:

This is the starting point: A DUPLO pig that needs to be put directly on LEGO pieces.
[image]

I decided to cut a DUPLO piece to regular LEGO size. A DUPLO 2x2 brick was converted to a ...
[image]

... 4x4 tile, modified, with 2x2 DUPLO studs. My methods were crude (metal saw and cutter), but it worked quite well. There is only little height difference to the surrounding LEGO plates, and the clutch power is really good:
[image]

This is an approximation of the final goal to use the DUPLO pig as a figurehead in a LEGO MOC/MOD:
[image]

**Edit:** The 27448 tiles finally arrived, but there was no way I could get clutch power. I measured 9.3 mm for the diameter of the tile ring, and 9.4 mm for the DUPLO stud. This difference is enough to loose any clutch power. Even with 4 tiles combined there was no binding strength at all. Other DUPLO animals showed same results. A DUPLO human figure, however, could at least have a little bit of bonding when the ring is pushed into the toe area.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: whoa, nice work! but it will make the purists squirm :)

Comment: @htmlcoderexe I know, this is a beyond-illegal technique. Hopefully, I can leave this path when the 27448 tiles arrive.

Comment: How much space there is between front/back legs? Uli's answer gave me an idea about using 4865/4865b part between the front/back legs. Either one (pig would be slightly of centre line) or both (would be centered) might fit into that gap.

Comment: @Alex the distance is something between 18.0 mm and 18.1 mm.

Answer (score 2):

Don't have too much experience with DUPLO, so my suggestion is based on my limited knowledge.

I'm not aware if there a way to attach pig directly to LEGO bricks, however I thought of a workaround. Here, green DUPLO figure legs represent your pig feet.

[image]

Comment: As mentioned, I did exactly that, but I want to avoid any extra Duplo brick or plate in my build. There must be some other solution. There must be LEGO pieces that somehow fit into Duplo feet.

Comment: Without seeing an example, you've described in the question, it wasn't very clear what kind of solution you have already tried. I've figured out whichever LEGO piece or assembly, that should be used to connect feet of a pig to LEGO bricks should be 12.8mm, 8 units or 32LDU in size.

Comment: I agree, normally the DUPLO plate solution is fine. However, this particular pig is going to be a sort of figurehead with as little as possible material underneath it.

Comment: My assumed size was a little wrong. Not entirely wrong, but won't dig much into details for now. So it turns out I got couple of DUPLO pieces. Caliper measured DUPLO stud diameter is 9.39 mm. Closest LEGO sized part I found for now is https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61485 where middle ring is 9.30mm (visually, both are same diameter). There are two more similar looking parts, however I don't own any of them to check dimensions: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3403 and https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=27448

Comment: LDraw parts used in LDCad show that 61485 and 27448 have inner ring of the same diameter, while 3403 has larger ring. And I just though 61485 part (if it fit) won't work for you, since you cannot fit two legs side-by-side using it. So 27448 is the only suggestion for now. I'm unable to test and confirm if this works and how good is the clutch power since none of my DUPLO has single stud connections.

Comment: Alex, thank you for the effort. Currently, I like the 2x2 modified tile (61485) more than the 4x4 turntables because it would fit under the pig, even if I can only attach one single leg (or maybe one front and one back leg). The 4x4 turntables would extend to the side (if I understand correctly that the middle ring acts as Duplo stud under a foot). Fun fact: 61485 only comes in white color.

Comment: I meant 27448, not 61485, of course.

Comment: I ordered some of the 27448 tiles to test this solution. If you want you can post it as separate answer. If it works it will be interesting for everyone.

Comment: Just share your results here. And if that works I'll amend answer with this suggestion to use 27448 part.

Comment: Alex, I just tried your solution with the 27448 tiles. Unfortunately, no success. See my own answer with the sawn up DUPLO brick for details.

Comment: @Aziraphale, oh well, at least we now know 0.1mm is a lot to get the right clutch power.

Answer (score 0):

Since Duplo is a 1:2 scale to Lego, I figured any Lego element twice the size of a regular stud would work. I tried out the pistons and piece [61485 (turntable)](https://brickset.com/parts/design-61485) before I saw this page, and I saw that it worked so I went online to investigate to see if anyone else had had the same idea. I also thought of the [27448](https://brickset.com/parts/design-27448) piece and your post confirmed it. Just in case you didn't know, I found out that a Technic pin - preferably [6558](https://brickset.com/parts/design-6558), [32054](https://brickset.com/parts/design-32054) (don't know about the friction-less or shorter ones) - is able to fit in a Duplo figure's hand, being that it is double the width of a bar piece.